# Omega & delta: rendering node title in a block

Tags: theming

Is it possible to render node fields as blocks with the omega theme and delta module? If I build a complex layout with zones and regions there can be situations where I need just the node title for example to be rendered in a block and then I can place it in the correct region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display Suite has just this feature available in Extras -> Other -> "Region to block." It doesn't work with the default view mode though so you will need to create/use a new view. I used "Full content." Then at the bottom of the Manage Display screen there will be a new vertical tab called "Block Regions." From here you create new regions which will be exposed as blocks. You can move any field into a block with this technique.

Answer (score 2):

Delta Blocks (sub module included with delta) makes that available as a block, as well as things like the author, terms, and post date. Combine with the context module and you can place the blocks in whatever order you like for particular content types.

Comment: Thanks. So here I can see the list I can expose as blocks admin/config/user-interface/delta-blocks
However, there's title and some other things but there's not custom fields I have added to my content type. I can't find post date neither.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [CCK Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/cck_blocks) module:

> This module allows you to create blocks from fields of the currently displayed node. It is very handy as a simple way to get fields appearing in a block, instead of in the main content region.